# casting variables at time of use or at time of declaration

Tags: javascript, casting

sInternal debate at work on best practice, I'm hoping some experienced people can chime in with "WHY", not just "you should...".

is there a functional difference between casting a variable (a) only when it is initialized or (b) when it is initialized AND every time you used it.

A.

```
var a = 1;
var b = 1;
... potential other code ...
var c = a + b;

var msg = '';
... potential other code ...
echo msg;
```

vs.

B.

```
var a = 1;
var b = 1;
... potential other code ...
var c = int( a ) + int( b );

var msg = '';
... potential other code ...
echo trim( msg );
```

A co-worker doesn't like all the 'extra' function calls to clutter his code and he claims there is an overhead that is not needed - unless you are dealing with user input, and even then you only need to 'cast' or operate once, when you put the user input into a var.

I take the opposite position of wanting to 'cast' every time I use the variable, especially before it goes into a data store, but I've become a proponent of even doing this type of operation when I'm displaying or using a var in any way. The only time I've had this bite me is when doing long floating point math (depending on how the cast operates).

I guess my though is that if I'm expecting a numeric value, or; in the above example, an integer. That casting on initialization works fine, but before I use the variable at any point, I want to use the type I'm expecting. So casting at the time of use seems prudent. This is especially true in loosely typed languages.

Can I get some thoughts on this? thank you

Comment: What is `int()`? Why don't you simply `+a` and `+b`? Considering `a` and `b` are already integers, why do you feel the need to perform extra parsing? Also `echo` is PHP, not JavaScript - perhaps this is where `int()` is coming from, too?

Answer (score 0):

There's no real sense to do it. If it's `int` then it's `int` until it changes.

Yes, you need to always check the info coming from user. But there's no real need to clutter your code and make the work on it so inconvenient. To work with, to read this code would be just hell. And also you add some load on the browser's interpreter, making scripts larger and working slower.

Comment: Its Javascript, not PHP. (Although the answer remains same for both)